# Failed to find element matching selector

Tags: selector, puppeteer

I am trying to use puppeteer to type in an input field but I get the following error.

```
Error: failed to find element matching selector "#cardCvc-input"
```

My code is:

```
await page.$eval('#cardCvc-input', e => e.value = "000")
```

The node in the DOM is as follows:

```
<input _ngcontent-ng-cli-universal-c1="" autocomplete="off" cccvc="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-
invalid ng-touched" id="cardCvc-input" maxlength="4" minlength="3" name="cardCvc" pattern="[0-9]{4}|[0-
9]{3}" required="" type="tel">
```

Hoping someone could help tell me what I am doing wrong. Note that when I check the page source, I don't actually see the DOM. It is a bunch of javascript code. Does that have anything to do with it?

Also noticed that there are iframe parent nodes.

Comment: are you waiting for the selector to appear before `eval`?

Comment: yes i am. see my comment to the answer below.

Comment: is it in an iframe?

Comment: how would i be able to tell?

Comment: i don't think its iframe. it looks like a bunch of javascript code that dynamically generates the HTML DOM

Comment: 1) check the parents of that input element in devtools and see if it's within an iframe. 2) does the element show up when you interact with it?

Comment: yes actually you are right. i do see the iframe parent node. There are two parent nodes that are iframes.

Comment: I wrote an answer, let me know if the answer didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the element is in an iframe you need to select the iframe first and then select the element:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('iframe'); //make sure you use the correct selector for the iframe
const iframeElement = await page.$('iframe'); //make sure you use the correct selector for the iframe
const frame = await iframeElement.contentFrame();
await frame.waitForSelector('#cardCvc-input');
await frame.$eval('#cardCvc-input', e => e.value = "000");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `waitForSelector` before calling `evaluate`. So you would wait for that DOM element to be created by the javascript code.

```js
await page.waitForSelector('#cardCvc-input');
await page.$eval('#cardCvc-input', e => e.value = "000")
```

Comment: That did not work. The DOM element does not show up on the page source no matter how long I wait.

I can only trace this DOM element from the developer tools.